# How to make setInterval to work even when a tab is inactive in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, setinterval

I'm making a music mixer, but when I switch to the other tabs in chrome, setInterval will stop calling a function.

I found this: [How can I make setInterval also work when a tab is inactive in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome) but my problem is, I'm using setInterval for changing volume smoothly between songs and not for animation. So I can't use Date() method. I don't even want to use something like jQuery, just pure Javascript.

Actually, my JS code is not small so theres link to js code: http://warhome.eu/play/player.js

and the PHP file: http://pastebin.com/FWJDW7e0

Thanks for help!

Comment: Did you see the [second answer to that question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12522580/298053) that mentions audio fading?

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it... Seems chrome supports setInterval even it is inactive, but it extends the interval. So solution is to use `onblur` and `onfocus` events to determine, if tab is inactive or not.

So final js code's here: http://warhome.eu/play/player_final.js